# оживить скрипт в IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Доброго дня!
Скрипт работает везде, кроме IE. Помогите разобраться. Что ему не нравится?

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(`button[data-modal-trigger]`);

for(let button of buttons) {
modalEvent(button);
}

function modalEvent(button) {
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const trigger = button.getAttribute('data-modal-trigger');
    const modal = document.querySelector(`[data-modal=${trigger}]`);
    const contentWrapper = modal.querySelector('.content-wrapper');
    const close = modal.querySelector('.close');

    close.addEventListener('click', () => modal.classList.remove('open'));
    modal.addEventListener('click', () => modal.classList.remove('open'));
    contentWrapper.addEventListener('click', (e) => e.stopPropagation());

    modal.classList.toggle('open');
});
}
```

Полный пример [тут](https://jsfiddle.net/malefikus13/Loruraza/)

Comment: непонятно, раз используете `jq`, то и используйте `jq` - для событий есть специальный метод `.on`. А так, вроде у ие `attachEvent`, а не `addEventListener`.

Comment: У вас используются кавычки из шаблонных строк из ES6, они не имеют поддержки в браузерах IE, советую вам заменить эти строки. А также вам надо заменить стрелочные функции, так как они тоже не поддерживаются. Чтобы посмотреть, где и что у вас не так пользуйтесь консолью браузера, она вам в большинстве случаев подскажет где ошибка.

Comment: Какая версия IE Должна быть?

Comment: Спасибо ребят! Я видимо много упустил по IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот, что нашел из того, что не поддерживается в IE в вашем коде:

1. У вас используются кавычки из [шаблонных строк](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) из ES6  - `
2. конструкции [for of](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)
3. [стрелочные функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
4. Также заменены [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) и [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const), они имеют базовую поддержку в IE-11, но не полностью поддерживаются, так что на всякий случай заменил их на `var`.

Вот код переделанный:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-modal-trigger]');
for(let i = 0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
    modalEvent(buttons[i]);
}

function modalEvent(button) {
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const trigger = button.getAttribute('data-modal-trigger');
    const modal = document.querySelector('[data-modal=' + trigger + ']');
    const contentWrapper = modal.querySelector('.content-wrapper');
    const close = modal.querySelector('.close');

    close.addEventListener('click', function() {modal.classList.remove('open')});
    modal.addEventListener('click', function() {modal.classList.remove('open')});
    contentWrapper.addEventListener('click', function(e) {e.stopPropagation()});

    modal.classList.toggle('open');
});
}
```

И полный код на jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/wur8gnpe/4/

Правда там теперь некорректно работает анимация, но это надо смотреть поддержку css браузера.

Comment: Ого, спасибо большое! IE для меня огромнейшая боль...низкий поклон.